# Выборка последнего элемента массива в MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Есть база данных **MongoDB**.
В ней содержатся данные пользователей, поля которых подобны таким:

```
{
        id: 0,
        isUser: true,
        messages: [
               {/* сообщение_1 */ },
               {/* сообщение_2 */ },
               {/* сообщение_3 */ },
        ]
}
```

И таких пользователей неограниченное количество.
Мне нужно сделать выборку **всех** пользователей, но только чтобы при этой выборке в массиве `messages` был только **последний** элемент, а не все.

Пробовал таким способом:

```
mongoClient.db('usersdb').collection('users')
        .find({ messages: { $slice: -1 } })
```

Результат выборки получается пустой.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно написать фильтр?

Comment: `messages[messages.langth - 1]`

Comment: как я укажу это в качестве фильтра для MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо указать запрашиваемый документ например по _id и вторым параметром фильтр

```
mongoClient.db('usersdb').collection('users').find(
 {_id:0},
 {_id:1, messages: { $slice: -1 } }
)
```

В этом примере ответ будет включать в себя поле _id и массив messages с последним элементом, все остальные поля будут проигнорированы.

Answer (score 0):

Используй оператор массива $last - возвращает последний элемент в массиве.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last-array-element/#mongodb-expression-exp.-last

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)